# $dL_g(1)$ is a section of a tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, tangent-bundle

Given a Lie Group, we have that the left multiplication $$L_g:G \to G$$ such that$L_g(x)=g  x$  induces the map $$dL_g(1): T_1G \to T_gG$$

If $v \in T_1G$, I have to prove that $dL_g(1)(v)$ is a smooth section of $T_gG$.

I know that a vector field on G is a smooth section of $T_gG$ and I tried to use this in order to solve the exercise, but a vector filed is map $F:M \to TM$, such that $F \circ \pi=Id_G $, where $M$ is a smooth manifold, $TM$ its tangent bundle and $\pi$ the fiber map. Conversely $dL_g(1)(v)$ does not go from $G$ to $T_gG$ so I don't know how to proceed.

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: The question asks you to show that $g\in G\mapsto dL_g(1)(v)\in TG$ is smooth section.

Comment: @user10354138 Ok, thanks! So I have to prove that there exists $p:dL_g(1)(v) \to G$ such that $p \circ \tilde v = ID_G$ where $ \tilde v: G \to dL_g(1)(v)$. Can I simply use $p(\tilde v(g))=g$?

Comment: No, you need to prove $\tilde{v}\colon g\mapsto dL_g(1)(v)$ is smooth (use logarithmic chart).  The fact that $\pi\circ\tilde{v}=1_G$ is given by $dL_g(1)(v)\in T_gG$.